# Swift UILabel OverlapsUIImage in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimage, uilabel

I'm making an UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell (CardCell). It contains an UIImage on the left an right next to it an UILabel.

I'm downloading the UIImages asynchronously from an URL, and Scal the UIImage to keep the aspect ratio of the image, th height should be 50 pixels, but the width can change (depending on the original width and height). I wrote a method to scale the Image, and it's working fine, but my UILabel overlaps the UIImage, like this:

[image]

I know that the Image is completely there because when I Tap and hold the cell (not really select the cell) I can see the Image underneath the UILabel, like this:

[image]

These are the constraints on the storyboard for the UIImage:
[image]

[image]

These are the constraints for the UILabel on the storyboard:
[image]

[image]

This is the code I wrote for scaling the downloaded Image:

```
func scaleImage(sourceImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {    
    var oldHeight = sourceImage.size.height
    var scaleFactor = 50/oldHeight

    var newWidth = sourceImage.size.width * scaleFactor
    var newHeight = oldHeight * scaleFactor

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight))
    sourceImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight))
    var newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

And this is the code for downloading the UIImage, rescaling it (calling the previous function) and setting the scaled UIImage in the cell:

```
func downloadImage(url: NSURL, cell: CardCell) {
    getDataFromUrl(url) { (data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else {return}
            let oldImage = UIImage(data: data)
            cell.logoImageView.image = self.scaleImage(oldImage!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove Leading space constraint of `UILabel` and assign Horizontal spacing with `UIImageView` it will do the job.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara No, I tried that before (and retried it right now) and it stays exactly the same.

Comment: according to screenshot thats only causing trouble, as well you can also assign `height` and `width` constraint to your `UIImageView` so that it stays uniform. Replacing Leading constraint with `horizontal spacing` would definitely work.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara Okay, it was a stupid mistake, I fixed it. Apparently has a custom UITableCell all the outlets you give to them, but also a standard UILabel named "textLabel". In my code I wrote: 
    cell.textLabel?.text = shop.name 

instead of

  cell.nameLabel?.text = shop.name,

Thanks to your answer I saw that the nameLabel was perfectly placed in the cell :D Thanks!